# opening db: `name db`: Read-only file system. KMM. Desktop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

Есть у кого-нибудь идеи как можно решить проблему: 
есть мультиплатформенный проект с sqldelight.
 Всё работает хорошо, ios, android.
А с desktop проблема.  Когда мы создаем в десктопе драйвер для базы данных, мы добавляем к мемори название бд чтобы она каждый раз не пересоздавалась:

```
JdbcSqliteDriver(JdbcSqliteDriver.IN_MEMORY + nameDb)
```

И если я запускаю через студию desktop приложение, всё хорошо, всё работает.

Но если я делаю dmg образ и устанавливаю приложение.
Я получаю ошибку: `opening db: name db: Read-only file system`.
 Я так понимаю, мак не даёт нашему собранному приложению читать файл базы данных. Как это обойти не пойму, есть идеи у кого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому будет полезно. После долгих поисков, нашёл такое решение:

```
actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
        val databasePath = File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "gtp.db")
        val driver: SqlDriver = JdbcSqliteDriver(url = "jdbc:sqlite:${databasePath.absolutePath}")
        return driver.apply {
            try {
                AppDatabase.Schema.create(this)
            }catch (e: Exception){

            }
        }

    }
```